# Python Selenium Web Driver: send_keys does not work in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, headless

Is there a way to log into a gmail account in headless mode? send_keys is works in normal mode but doesn't work when I use headless mode.

This is my code:

```
chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//A[@id="gb_70"]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file('main-page.png')
    x = True
    while True:
        try:
            print('trying to paste email')
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//INPUT[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys(keys['emailUser'])
            print('email entered')
            break
        except ElementNotInteractableException:
            pass
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            pass
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
```

My terminal never prints 'email entered'

Comment: How about your xPath  for input field. is it correct ? If xpath is correct you can simply enter text using.
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys(emailUser')

Answer (score 0):

In the options try adding this argument

```
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent = my-user-agent")
```

`my-user-agent` is different for every system, to check your agent kindly google `my user agent` and insert it in the options.

Also along with this I feel that in your code, `while` is unnecessary, you may remove that.
Since the textbox you are trying to access takes time to load, so try using explicit wait here while extracting it

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#identifierId")))
```

When you have to enter text and press enter kindly update your code with the below snippet:

```
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#identifierId")))
username.send_keys("Emailuser", Keys.ENTER)
```